# Haskell - Recursive function - (User input, list of some sort) -> (list of some sort)

Tags: haskell, recursion

hi I need a recursive function where I give the function an input (IO String) and a list of some sort. This function will then based of the last element of the list and the user input, give me a new element. This element will be put in the list and it will be returned. The problem is that I always get an error with the input.

```
func :: IO String -> [Grid] -> [Grid] 
func gridList = input <- getInput
         do something...
```

I know the definition of the function is wrong, but I have no idea have I am gonne make it right. If someone have any suggestion, I would be greatful! :)

NOTE: getInput is a function which gives me a IO String

Comment: Your function signature looks like it should be `[Grid] -> IO [Grid]`. Your `IO String` isn't actually a parameter. You're pulling it in from a globally defined `getInput`.

Comment: World like a charm, thanks ! <3

Comment: You might consider breaking out a "pure" function `String -> [Grid] -> [Grid]` to do the logic. Then you call this new function from a function such as the one you have here that does the IO and passes the string into the new function.